# CSS-Grid Image Gallery Layout Bottom Baseline is inconsistent for different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am currently experimenting with layouts for my photography website and I want to use CSS Grid Layout because I can reorder images for different screen sizes in a very flexible way. I am aware, that this layout can be achieved with flex or even with divs set to `dispay: inline-block` as well, however that solution does not allow me to flexibly reorder the images.

[image: Portfolio Showcase]

It looks fine like this, however if I resize my browser window or just display it on another screen, the bottom baseline get's screwed up as seen in the following picture.

[image: Bottom Baseline Messed Up]

This is how the relevant HTML looks

```
<div class="galleryblock">
        <div class="image1"><img src="static/photos/plansee-glow.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image2"><img src="static/photos/giaupass.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image3"><img src="static/photos/eibsee.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image4"><img src="static/photos/hintersee.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image5"><img src="static/photos/marilena.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image6"><img src="static/photos/jack.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image7"><img src="static/photos/loser-cassi.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image8"><img src="static/photos/plansee-hype.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image9"><img src="static/photos/obersee-huette.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image10"><img src="static/photos/plansee-birdseye.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image11"><img src="static/photos/mariagern.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image12"><img src="static/photos/neuschwanstein.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image13"><img src="static/photos/Kirkjufell2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image14"><img src="static/photos/eibsee-bruecke.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image15"><img src="static/photos/obersee-mood.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
```

And this is the relevant CSS

```
div.galleryblock{
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 0.81fr 1fr 0.81fr 1fr;


    grid-template-areas:
        "img1  img2  img3 img4   img5"
        "img1  img7  img3 img9   img5"
        "img6  img7  img8 img9   img10"
        "img6  img12 img8 img14  img10 "
        "img11 img12 img13 img14 img15";

    grid-gap: 0.5em;
}
```

And all the divs with class image1 to image15 get assigned to the respective grid template area by using `grid-area: imgX;`.

I am aware, that the images have different aspect ratios, while the landscape format pictures are 3:2, the portrait format pictures are 4:5. However, every column should be of equal height because the sum of the pictures (1 landscape and 2 portrait) is always the same. If I divide the height of a landscape format picture by the height of a portrait format picture, I get 0.8 as the kind ratio between the heights. That's why I experimented with values around `0.81fr` and `0.84fr` in my css for `grid-template-rows`. Depending on the screen size one of those values works perfectly or messed up the baseline.

I also experimented with using divs that have the photos as the background image, but then I will have to manually set the height with JavaScript and that's something I'd like to avoid if possible. I looked through different attributes for css grid but I could not find anything that just truncates the image if it's too long and provides a fixed bottom baseline.

Is my use case just not possible for grid layout because of the different height content? In productions I would have blocks like this repeated. I know I could use a column layout with flex, but in smaller screens this would push the images that are on the top right very far down and I would prefer to have the images that come first on the big screen to also come first on smaller screens, if you know what I mean.

Thanks a lot in advance for actually investing time in my problem, I would not have posted this if I didn't try to solve it myself with a lot of trying and failing and googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `align-self: end` for the bottom images solved the problem. This means, that the gaps between the images won't be exactly the same, but it's not visible unless you look really really closely.